# AsyncTask - using element by findviewbyid of different fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I am calling AsyncTask class from Fragment1 and trying to store the result of doInBackground() in Fragment2's listview.

But when I use the view of the Fragment2 to access the element like

```
cartlistview=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listview1);
```

It throws **a null pointer exception** stating v is null.

I wrote the storing code in onPosteExecute() function

```
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
     MyCartFragment mcf=new MyCartFragment(); //2nd Fragment
     View v=mcf.getView();         
     cartlistview=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listView1); // ERROR HERE

     // Code starting from here is not causing any problems - ignoreable.
     Cursor res=databaseHelper.onView();
     int len=res.getCount();

     listCartItems = new ArrayList<CartItems>();
     listCartItems.add(new CartItems(9,"Item Name", "Quantity", "Price","Delete"));

    if(len==0)
    {
        //Toast.makeText(this.getContext(),"Cart is Empty.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        statusOfCart=false;
    }
    else {
        while (res.moveToNext()) {
            int id=res.getInt(0);
            String itemname = res.getString(1).toString();  // 0 is id, 1 is name, 2 is qty, 3 price
            String itemqty = Integer.toString(res.getInt(2));
            String itemprice = Integer.toString(res.getInt(3)); 
            listCartItems.add(new CartItems(id,itemname, itemqty, itemprice,"X"));
        }
    }
    CartListAdapter cartListAdapter = new CartListAdapter(mcf.getContext(),R.layout.cartlist_layout, listCartItems);
    cartlistview.setAdapter(cartListAdapter);

}
```

Comment: in view you have to inflate with `xml` file not the `java` file

Comment: Why do you implement an AsyncTask inside one Fragment and display results in another Fragment?

Comment: inserting items data to the db table in add-to-cart-fragment(1st fragment) and displaying the result of the db table in the cart-fragment(2nd fragment). 
I am newb. Please tell me if theres a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to inflate your view before look for stuff in it.

```
 MyCartFragment mcf=new MyCartFragment(); //2nd Fragment
 View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false); // <= inflate your view
 cartlistview=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listView1); // v is not null anymore
```

`Fragment.getView()` will only works once the view has been inflated already

Comment: what do i pass in place of 'container' ?

Comment: the parent of your view